# Getting Actual Excel cell value without formatting in VSTO

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm using VSTO to get excel cell value, when I wrote 3:00 in a cell and trying to get this value from code it returns 0.125, could anybody help me to get the actual text value without excel formatting . Here's me code

```
  Range selectedRange = Target.Application.Selection as Range;
  foreach (Range cell in selectedRange)
        {
            string val = cell.Value2; // 
        }
```

Comment: What is your code? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Do you have `Value2` as an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are right, you should always post some code, but this one is simple. Just use `MyCell.Text` instead of `MyCell.Value`

Comment: Thanks Doug, I have pasted my code, I'm using value2 which gives the the above result, when using MyCell.Text it gives me the actual cell value but in case of mobile no for example it gives me formatted decimal number like that 2.01008E+11

Comment: If I format using Excel's phone format, i.e., `[<=9999999]###-####;(###) ###-####` and enter 5037774444 in a cell, `ActiveCell.Text` returns (503) 777-4444, which is what I would expect. It should return exactly what you see in the cell. How is your cell formatted and what do you see in it? And also, did my answer work for your original question involving 3:00?

Comment: ok I got it working using some checks on the text property